# Hover only when not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a hover on MENU2,3 and submenu's like the hover on MENU 1&2.

I can only get the hover on the title class. I'm trying to get hover on .ui .accordion .item when the title class below does not have .active class is this possible?

```js
 $(".ui.accordion").accordion();
```

```css
/*
.ui.accordion.item:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    color: #ffffff;
}
*/

.ui.menu .active.item:hover, .ui.vertical.menu .active.item:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.ui.inverted.menu .active.item {
   background-color: transparent;
}
  
.ui.accordion.item > .title:NOT(.active):hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ui left fixed vertical inverted menu">
         
        <div class="item">
          <form method="POST" action="#">
            <div class="ui fluid inverted transparent icon input">
              <input type="text" name="search">
              <i class="search icon"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none;">
          </form>      
        </div>        

        <a class="item" href="#">MENU 1</a>
        <a class="item" href="#">MENU 2</a>   
        <div class="ui accordion item inverted">
          <div class="title item" style="padding: 0px;">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> MENU 3
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <a class="item" href="#">SUBMENU 1</a>
            <a class="item" href="#">SUBMENU 2</a>
          </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="ui accordion item inverted">
          <div class="title item" style="padding: 0px;">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> MENU 4
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <a class="item" href="#">SUBMENU 1</a>
            <a class="item" href="#">SUBMENU 2</a>
          </div>    
        </div>        
    </div>  
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mpb7cfx/303/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question
http://jsfiddle.net/4mpb7cfx/306/

```
.ui.accordion.item {
  padding:0px;
}

.ui.accordion.item > .title {
  padding: .78571em .95em;
}

.ui.menu .active.item:hover, .ui.vertical.menu .active.item:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.ui.inverted.menu .active.item {
   background-color: transparent;
}

.ui.accordion.item > .title:NOT(.active):hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ui.accordion.item > .content > .item {
  padding-left: 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override hover to default style when .active set

```
.ui.accordion.item > .title.active:hover {
    //set default
}

.ui.accordion.item > .title:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I can get the hover to work on parrent, my problem is when it's active I want the hover on parent to disappear. I don't want hover on title
http://jsfiddle.net/4mpb7cfx/305/